# Objective-C NSRegularExpressions, finding first occurrence of numbers in a string

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, cocoa, nsregularexpression

I'm pretty green at regex with Objective-C. I'm having some difficulty with it.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b([1-9]+)\\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regError];
if (regError) {
    NSLog(@"%@",regError.localizedDescription);
}
__block NSString *foundModel = nil;
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:self.model options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.model length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    foundModel = [self.model substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]];
    *stop = YES;
}];
```

All I'm looking to do is take a string like

```
150A
```

And get

```
150
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First the problems with the regex:

1. You are using word boundaries (`\b`) which means you are only
   looking for a number that is by itself (e.g. 15 but not 150A).
2. Your number range does not include `0` so it would not capture `150`. It needs to be `[0-9]+` and better yet use `\d+`.

So to fix this, if you want to capture any number all you need is `\d+`. If you want to capture anything that starts with a number then only put the word boundary at the beginning `\b\d+`.

Now to get the first occurrence you can use 
`-[regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:options:range:]`

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b\\d+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regError];
if (regError) {
    NSLog(@"%@",regError.localizedDescription);
}

NSString *model = @"150A";
NSString *foundModel = nil;
NSRange range = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:model options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(0, [model length])];
if(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    foundModel = [model substringWithRange:range];
}

NSLog(@"Model: %@", foundModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `.*?(\d+).*?` ?

[Demo:](http://regex101.com/r/wC9nZ2)
That would backreference the number and you would be able to use it wherever you want.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work as `*` does a *longest* match, so with the input `150A` the first `.*` matches `15`, the `(\d+)` matches `0`, and the final `.*` matches `A`.

Comment: Sorry, I forget the "lazy" sign

Comment: Yes, *shortest* match will do it, but you only need the first one surely? (And of course there are other re's that will do it as well, however a pattern such as @Joe's matches only the required number which is good.)